# cd command not working

Tags: command-line, bash

[image]

When I'm trying to run the `cd` command on my virtual pc is shows error as shown in pic above. How can I change the directory?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your command and/or error messages. Copy and paste the _text_ instead so that we can as well copy and paste your commands into our terminal windows to reproduce the error without re-typing.

Answer (score 3):

You simply misspelled it: In Ubuntu (and generally in Unix systems), file and directory names are case-sensitive and the directory's name is `Desktop`:

```bsh
cd Desktop   # if you are in your home directory (relative path)
cd ~/Desktop # if you are anywhere else (absolute path)
```