# Trying to scan my library for the first time in Plex lead me to trying Chng Dir to my external drive

Tags: external-hdd, cd, plex

As the title says, I'm now trying to change the directory to external usb drive so I can figure out why I can't get Plex to see the mp4s. Novice Linux user here. I've read and read and it seems that I've tried every suggestion that I could find. All the responses (probably from expert users) make it seem so simple. The simple answer that I always see is `cd /media/elements`. My external drive is "Elements". The block quote is the return that I get.
steeldriver solved my problem. I always have a brain freeze about the case sensitivity of file names. It's hard to get away from the old Windows habits! Thanks.

```
tommy@Desktop-Inspiron-3910:~$ cd /media/elements
bash: cd: /media/elements: No such file or  directory
tommy@Desktop-Inspiron-3910:~$
```

Comment: You can use the `ls` command to verify the name ex. `ls /media`, `ls /media/tommy`. Don't forget file and directory names are case sensitive so `elements` is not the same as `Elements`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cd command not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010539/cd-command-not-working)